# Color blending per pixel

Tags: java

I'm trying  to understand graphics. Now I'm stuck at color blending. I have tried to use some basic algorithms that would merge colors in rgb. Now I'd like to merge them like in real life i.e Yellow + Blue = green. I have a method like this.

```
package com.boxonix.light.utils;

public class Utils {

   public static int rgbToHex(int r, int g, int b) {
      return (1048576 * r) + (255 * g) + b;
   }

   public static int blendPixels(int r, int g, int b, double alpha, int bgPixel){   
      return 0;
   }

   public static int getRed(int color) {
      int red = Math.floorDiv(color, 1048576);
      return red;
   }

   public static int getGreen(int color) {
      int green = Math.floorDiv(color % 65536, 256);
      return green;
   }

   public static int getBlue(int color) {
      int blue = Math.floorDiv(color % 1048576, 256);
      return blue;
   }
}
```

r,g,b are colors represent the pixel that is coming over the background pixel (bgPix) alpha is transparency(0.0 - 1.0). I can convert bgPix to r1, g1, b1. Now I need to blend them, Help! :D

Comment: "Blending" two colors really means taking the weighted average of them. So if you have a black background (`000000`) and white foreground (`FFFFFF`) with alpha=25%, and you want to blend them, you'd take the weighted average of these. Note that each component is averaged separately - it's really the weighted average of `[0x00, 0x00, 0x00]` and `[0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF)`. `0.75*0x00 + 0.25*0xFF = 0x3F` so your answer would be `[0x3F, 0x3F, 0x3F]`. Good luck, and feel free to show us some actual code if you're stuck.

Comment: `"Blending" two colors really means taking the weighted average of them` : That's wrong. averaging gives bad, very ugly results. If you want to blend two colors like real-life, use the formula `sqrt(ColA^2 + ColB^2)/2`

Comment: @GuillaumeF. Can you explain me more in detail how your formula works, since I don't think I know what you're aiming at.

Comment: Minute Physics for you : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKnqECcg6Gw

Comment: This made me note a mistake in the above formula, the correct one is `sqrt((ColA^2 + ColB^2)/2)` as seen in the video.

Comment: Great it works, now if I want to reduce it to like 25% or something, witch part am I supposed to multiply with alpha and 1-alpha?

Comment: `sqrt(((AlphaA*ColA)^2 + (AlphaB*ColB)^2)/(AlphaA + AlphaB))`

Comment: A side note: These computations look odd. You should not use these "magic" constants. Hex codes have the nice property of "visually" showing which bytes are cout out. Alternatively, you can shift the relevant part into the relevant byte. E.g. to obtain the green component (as a value in 0...255) from an RGB value, you can use `int g = (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF`

Comment: Thank you guys, this has been very helpful!

Comment: As usual, things are a bit more complex than they seem at the first glance. You are referring to color mixing "as in real life", where "yellow+blue=green". This is referred to as [subtractive color mixing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtractive_color) (in contrast to [additive color mixing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_color), which is more common in many computer graphics contexts). Alpha values add a considerable complexity here, due to the different options for [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing](alpha compositing). Maybe I'll extend this to an answer later.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to alpha blend a foreground color on top of some background color.  Happily, it's as simple as:

```
alpha * foregroundColor + (1 - alpha) * backgroundColor
```

The idea is that only part of the color comes from the foreground color, and the rest (`1 - alpha`) comes from the background.  You can see this intuitively if you think about it: if alpha is 0, then all the color comes from the background; if alpha is 1, all of it comes from the foreground.

Example code using your method definitions above:

```
public static int blendPixels(int r, int g, int b, double alpha, int bgPixel) {   
   int blendedRed = (int)Math.round(alpha * r + (1.0 - alpha) * getRed(bgPixel));
   int blendedGreen = (int)Math.round(alpha * g + (1.0 - alpha) * getGreen(bgPixel));
   int blendedBlue = (int)Math.round(alpha * b + (1.0 - alpha) * getBlue(bgPixel));
   return rgbToHex(blendedRed, blendedGreen, blendedBlue);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Pretty sure you have to do each channel separately. The example I gave in my comment, 0.75*black + 0.25*white... your code says `0.25*0xFFFFFF` which would be either `0x400000` (a rather dark red) or `0x3FFFFF` (electric blue-cyan), depending on how you round. Not gray.

Comment: @dcsohl Sorry, you're absolutely right.  I was a bit too quick to answer.  I just edited my answer above accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Not actually an answer, but here is a quick implementation of color blending per pixel according to the formula

> alpha * foregroundColor + (1 - alpha) * backgroundColor

which seems wrong - look at the screenshot - and feel free to use the code for testing purposes.

**Screenshot:**

[image: pixel blending done wrong]

**Code:**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Random;

public class Program {
    static JFrame mainFrame;
    static JPanel view;
    static JLabel fgLabel;
    static JSlider fgTrack;
    static JLabel alphaLabel;
    static JSlider alphaTrack;
    static JLabel bgLabel;
    static JSlider bgTrack;

    static int fg;
    static float alpha;
    static int blend;
    static int bg;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //setup application
        mainFrame = new JFrame() {{
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setContentPane(new JPanel() {{
                setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                setSize(640, 480);
                setPreferredSize(getSize());
                add(new JPanel() {{
                    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                    add(fgLabel = new JLabel());
                    add(fgTrack = new JSlider(0, 100) {{
                        setOrientation(JSlider.VERTICAL);
                        setMajorTickSpacing(25);
                        setMinorTickSpacing(5);
                        setPaintTrack(true);
                        setPaintTicks(true);
                        addChangeListener(e -> {
                            fg = Color.getHSBColor(getValue() / 100f, 1f, 1f).getRGB();
                            fgLabel.setText("fg=" + rgbToString(fg));
                            view.repaint();
                        });
                    }});
                    add(alphaLabel = new JLabel());
                    add(alphaTrack = new JSlider(0, 100) {{
                        setOrientation(JSlider.VERTICAL);
                        setMajorTickSpacing(25);
                        setMinorTickSpacing(5);
                        setPaintTrack(true);
                        setPaintTicks(true);
                        addChangeListener(e -> {
                            alpha = getValue() / 100f;
                            blend = blendPixels(fg, alpha, bg);
                            alphaLabel.setText("<html>alpha=" + alpha+"<br>blend=" + rgbToString(blend));
                            view.repaint();
                        });
                    }});
                    add(bgLabel = new JLabel());
                    add(bgTrack = new JSlider(0, 100) {{
                        setOrientation(JSlider.VERTICAL);
                        setMajorTickSpacing(25);
                        setMinorTickSpacing(5);
                        setPaintTrack(true);
                        setPaintTicks(true);
                        addChangeListener(e -> {
                            bg = Color.getHSBColor(getValue() / 100f, 1f, 1f).getRGB();
                            bgLabel.setText("bg=" + rgbToString(bg));
                            view.repaint();
                        });
                    }});
                }}, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                add(view = new JPanel() {
                    @Override
                    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                        super.paintComponent(g);

                        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
                        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

                        //"transparent" background
                        final int m = 8;
                        for (int r = 0, x = 0; x < getWidth(); r++, x += m) {
                            for (int c = 0, y = 0; y < getHeight(); c++, y += m) {
                                g2.setColor((r + c) % 2 == 0 ? Color.WHITE : Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                                g2.fillRect(x, y, m, m);
                            }
                        }

                        //circles
                        final int d = Math.min(getWidth() / 2, getHeight());
                        g2.setColor(new Color(bg));
                        g2.fillOval(d, 0, d, d);
                        g2.setColor(new Color(blend));
                        g2.fillOval(d / 2, 0, d, d);
                        g2.setColor(new Color(fg));
                        g2.fillOval(0, 0, d, d);
                    }
                }, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            }});
        }};

        //randomize values
        Random rng = new Random();
        fgTrack.setValue(rng.nextInt(100));
        alphaTrack.setValue(rng.nextInt(100));
        bgTrack.setValue(rng.nextInt(100));

        //display
        mainFrame.pack();
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static String rgbToString(int rgb) {
        return Integer.toHexString(rgb).toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT);
    }

    public static int rgbToHex(int r, int g, int b) {
        return (1 << 16) * r
                + (1 << 8) * g
                + (1 << 0) * b;
    }

    public static int blendPixels(int fgPixel, float alpha, int bgPixel) {
        return rgbToHex(
                blendPixelComponent(getRed(fgPixel), alpha, getRed(bgPixel)),
                blendPixelComponent(getGreen(fgPixel), alpha, getGreen(bgPixel)),
                blendPixelComponent(getBlue(fgPixel), alpha, getBlue(bgPixel))
        );
    }

    public static int blendPixelComponent(int fgComp, float alpha, int bgComp) {
        final float beta = 1 - alpha;
        return Math.round(alpha * fgComp + beta * bgComp);
    }

    public static int getRed(int color) {
        return (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
    }

    public static int getGreen(int color) {
        return (color >> 8) & 0xFF;
    }

    public static int getBlue(int color) {
        return (color >> 0) & 0xFF;
    }
}
```